# Why is the page number for Contents wrong?

Tags: table-of-contents

So I have a longer document. I generate the Contents page using

```
\tableofcontents
```

and use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Contents}
```

so it appears in the table of contents. Now my problem is that it has the wrong page number. Contents starts at page vii but is stored in the table of contents as on page viii. I tried switching the two statements around which resulted in a page number of vi instead of vii.

How can I fix this problem? I am using the srcbook documentclass

Comment: This depends on the position of your `\addcontentsline` - before or after `\tableofcontents`. Small tip: Use `tocbibind` package or the KOMA built-in support for this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yeah but if I put it before \tableofcontents it has page number vi and afterwards it gets page number vii... I want it at vii. I will look into tocbibind

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks for the tocbibind tip. It worked!